# Abelian groups of order $p^4$, where $p$ is prime

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups

> List up to isomorphism all abelian groups of order $p^4$, where $p$ is prime.

I'm thinking of trying to approach this question by look at the groups isomorphic to a product of distinct cyclic groups of order $p^4$.

But for what $\mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b \times . . .$ does the group $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_a \times \mathbb{Z}_b \times . . .$ have order $p^4$?

Would this be for $G \cong \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p?$ And if so, what other groups have order $p^4$?

Comment: A product of groups $G \times H$ has order $|G| \times |H|$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Does this mean the the abelian groups are isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_p^4$, $\mathbb{Z}_{2p}^2$ and $\mathbb{Z}_{3p} \times \mathbb{Z}_p$?

Comment: That's in the right direction. You want $p^2$ and $p^3$, not $2p$ and $3p$.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan That's great, thank you!

Comment: You're also missing one group!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Oh yeah, $\mathbb{Z}_{p^4}$

Comment: Oh, sorry, I misspoke. You're still missing a group!

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm still missing a group? I'm not sure what that would be

Comment: Apparently, $\mathbb{Z}_{p^2} \times \mathbb{Z}_p \times \mathbb{Z}_p$.

Comment: @IvanNeretin Thank you! Is there a way of working out how many isomorphic abelian groups there are? So I can check if I missed any.

Comment: I think this [OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A000688) would do (scroll down to the "Formula" section).

Comment: Consider how many elements  there are of order $p^n$ ,for $n\in \{1,2,3,4\}$,  in each of the 5 groups in the previous comments, to show that no 2 of them are isomorphic. The order of a member $a$ of a group is the least $n\in N$ such that $a^n=1$.

Answer (score 1):

*Summarising the comments . . .*

The groups are:

$$\begin{align}
&\Bbb Z_p^4, \\
&\Bbb Z_{p^2}\times \Bbb Z_p^2, \\
&\Bbb Z_{p^2}^2, \\
&\Bbb Z_{p^3}\times \Bbb Z_p, \\
&\Bbb Z_{p^4}.
\end{align}$$

As mentioned in [this OEIS entry](http://oeis.org/A000688), the number of such groups for $p^k$ is the number of [partitions](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of $k$.