# Abelian groups which satisfy the isomorphism $\frac{A}{N}\cong \frac {\mathbb{Z}}{p^3\mathbb{Z}}$

Tags: group-theory

Let $p$ be a prime.The order of Abelian group $A$ is $p^{4}$.
Let $N$ be a subgroup of order $p$ and satisfies $\frac{A}{N}\cong \frac{ \mathbb{Z}}{p^{3} \mathbb{Z}}$.

I want to find all of these $A$ up to isomorphisms.

Could you give an answer or hint to prove this ?

Comment: For all candidates of order $p^4$ see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1622128/abelian-groups-of-order-p4-where-p-is-prime).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A$ needs to contain an element of order $p^3$ or larger. This leaves you only with $\Bbb Z/p^4\Bbb Z$ and $\Bbb Z/p^3\Bbb Z\oplus \Bbb Z/p\Bbb Z$ as candidates.